# Performance issue with 1 to many relationship in SQL database

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

I started working on a project very similar to SO. I have created a database (*Code First* EF - 5 Sql server 2012) for my app which have lots of table including *Questions* ans *Answers*. There is a *one - to - many* relationship between both of these tables ( *one question can have multiple answers* ). Now as SO does i also want to show the *Answers* count for each question on the questions list view.

The approach which is obvious is that (*if Answers and Questions have 1 to many relationship so each question entity have a List of Answers objects with it*) so we can write a simple statement:

```
   question.Answers.Count;
```

But i have a performance doubt with this query. First i tell how i decided to do this ( *i have no much experience with database so please correct me if i am on a wrong path* )

I created an extra column in Question table name `AnswerCount` which will updated each time when an answer for the question is Inserted Or Deleted by User. For this i wrote an sql trigger executes on insert or delete events on Answer table. Here is the trigger:

```
Create TRIGGER [dbo].[trg_Answer_INSERT_Delete]
ON [dbo].[Answer] 
AFTER INSERT, DELETE 
AS BEGIN
   DECLARE @id as int = 0,
           @count as int = 0;

   SELECT TOP 1 @id = QuestionId FROM inserted; 

   IF @id = 0
    BEGIN
    SELECT TOP 1 @id = QuestionId FROM deleted; 
    END

   SELECT @count = count(*) FROM Answer where QuestionId = @id; 

   UPDATE Question
   SET AnswerCount = @count
   WHERE Id = @id;         
END
```

I am doing all this overhead because isn't efficient to save the count in a column and just access the column value whenever want to show the count instead of calling a Count function on a navigation property *(Answers)* each time when we want to show the answers count for the question ??

Can anybody please put a detail light on this scenario ?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have decided to denormalise your database in the hope of performance gains. Do you know that this will improve performance? Have you done any profiling? If not I would normalise first and then look at refactoring the schema to store the count only if you actually have performance issues. I'm not sure what SO does or any other site but I'd want to be sure of the performance gains before going down this road. Perhaps someone else will know and give a nice answer.

If you are thinking that performance will be bad because you have to retrieve the answer collection for each question then this is not true. You can always write Linq to Entity queries that return an anonymous type (or an actual type that holds a question, answerCount pair).

```
var query = context.questions.GroupJoin(context.answers,
q => q.QuestionId,
a => a.QuestionId,
(q, aGroup) => new
{
Question = q,
AnswerCount = aGroup.Count()
});
```

Above will return an anonymous type which contains a question and the answer count without materialising the answers. You could refine it further to only return an anonymous type of the question title and answer count if you wished.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it is absolutely certain that adding an AnswerCount column to the Questions table (denormalization) will improve *query* performance; the trade-off is that *write-performance* takes a hit (it could be just a light love-tap or it could be a real wallop)  when the trigger does `SELECT @count = count(*) FROM Answer where QuestionId = @id;`.  Instead of issuing this select you could simply increment or decrement the value in the question's AnswerCount column depending upon whether it was an answer-insert or an answer-deletion. P.S.  Make AnswerCount default value = 0.